# The Forty Rules of Love - what kind of "love"?

Tags: elif-shafak, the-forty-rules-of-love

In Elif Safak's novel *The Forty Rules of Love*, Shams has a list of rules which he calls the Forty Rules of Love and encourages everyone to live by. What kind of "love" are these rules trying to govern? There are many different types of love (4, 7, or 8, according to who you ask): romantic love, family love, love between friends, love of God, ...

Do Shams's rules cover all of these equally, or are they focused on some more than others? (For example, he seems [quite bad at romantic love](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8458/17), but there's a lot more to him than just love of God.)